# How to make debugger break every time execution invokes a certain script file in Edge/Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

I am debugging a Typescript web app, and I've never done web dev before. The project consists of multiple script files, multiple libraries.

When I execute the application in the debugger, I only care what goes on in one file and one file only (let's call it `my_script.ts`).

When I step through functions, I have to go through libraries as well, and it's time-consuming.
Is it possible to set some kind of global break point on the whole `my_script.ts` file so that every time execution returns from some `foo_lib.js` or `foo_lib.ts` back to `my_script.ts` the code execution halts regardless of where in `my_script.ts` we end up?

At the same time, once I am inside `my_script.ts` and resume the execution, I don't want it to break on every single line of `my_script.ts`.
I.e., I am looking for a way to invoke a breakpoint for `foo.js`=>`my_script.ts` transitions only so that I could just hit **continue** when I end up in an outside library and return to `my_script.ts` instantly.

UPD: If there is an extension that can help me, I'll take that too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`debugger` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger):

> ```js
> function potentiallyBuggyCode() {
>     debugger;
>     // do potentially buggy stuff to examine, step through, etc.
> }
> ```
>
> When the debugger is invoked, execution is paused at the debugger statement. It is like a breakpoint in the script source.

Other than that, you may need to rely on the breakpoint features of the browser you are using to debug. Chrome offers [function breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#function) "when you want to pause whenever a specific function is called", and you can further set up [line of code breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#loc) which you can then [disable](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#manage-loc) after your code is initialized.

If manually disabling the breakpoints is too difficult or cumbersome, you can also set [conditional breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#conditional-loc) to narrowly specify the conditions where you break, including a manual boolean field you manage in your library.

Comment: Is there an extension that can do what I need?

Comment: @InfiniteLoop I'm not aware of one. One might exist, but SO isn't a great place for software/library recommendations [due to its format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource).

Comment: Sad. Maybe I should write one. :)

Comment: Also, do you know of any way to have a separate window/section with variables to track their values similarly how Visual Studio allows you to do with C++ code? Having to go between them and hover over them with a mouse to get current values is not very convenient.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop Do you mean [the Watch panel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/reference/#watch)?